# Codeigniter escape_str undo to pure HTML

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just try to use Codeigniter escape_str function it's working good, but when i try to get data and show in front side then some extra code showing. any way for replace those all extra symbol.

This is the function

```
$content = $this->db->escape_str($content);
```

I'm trying to input below data from HTML texarea

```
Hello all how are you?

I'm from cox's bazar. see you again.
```

but when i try to echo it then i'm getting like this

```
Hello all how are you?\r\n\r\nI\'m from cox\'s bazar. see you again.
```

It should return same as my input. please help me for solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `html_escape()` CodeIgniter function:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html?highlight=html_escape#html_escape

Comment: us it for insert data